# wireguard запуск нескольких конфигов

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, wireguard

сам новичок в линусках и настройках. Поэтому скорее всего глупые вопрос будет.
Вот я поднял vpn wireguard для себя на одном конфиге (wg0.conf). Там прописал 3 пира и все работает окей, но если я хочу допустим дать доступ другу, мне лучше создать отдельный конфиг для него и можно ли это вообще реализовать? Потому что когда я пытаюсь поднять второй конфиг аналогичный первому он дает мне ошибку.
Вот конфиг:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.5/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
PostUp = iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
PostDown = iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
ListenPort = 51821
PrivateKey = ***

[Peer]
PublicKey = ****
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.6/32
```

Или же всех тупо фигачить в один конфиг?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас конфиг неправильный. AllowdIPs - это до каких IP можно ходить по туннелю. А  address - это IP клиента. А вообще я вам рекомендую использовать скрипт easy-wg. У меня около 15 клиентов. Я бы десять раз закричал на стену если бы каждый раз прописывал конфиг вручную.
Ссылка на скрипт:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/burghardt/easy-wg-quick/master/easy-wg-quick
```

Для настройки я руководствовался [этой](https://unixhost.pro/clientarea/knowledgebase/63/ustanovka-wireguard.html) статьёй.

Comment: Просто мне для того что бы вставить в конфиг новых пиров нужно стопить сервер, ибо на рабочем wireguard'де текстовый редактор nano не сохраняет настройки конфига. Ясно, что никто не будет делать что-то важное с включенным VPN, но просто ради интереса как можно было бы делать без отключения.
А по поводу AllowdIPs и address, делал как в видосе/статьях, у меня все работает и показывает IP именно моего сервера.
А можете дать ссылку на этот easy-wg?

Comment: Оно без выключения работать не будет. У меня через скрипт сделано так. Есть главный конфиг (где ты прописываешь настройки сервера). Там же импорты клиентов. При добавлении нового клиента, нужно его импортировать в основной конфиг (это делает скрипт), переместить новый конфиг в /etc, и ребутнуть сервис для применения настроек. В этот момент связь пропадёт. Я добавлю ссылку на скрипт и на статью как это использовать в ответ